# Why is this simple ng-bind and ng-show not working?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I am trying to display data fetched from Google's Place Service. For some reason, I can log the object to the console inside the controller but in the HTML file the directives simply do not get filled in. Since I am not using a map, I passed a div element in for the node. There seemed to be no guide online for displaying attributes this way so I tried assigning the object to a scope variable and displaying it that way. `$scope.location` prints a perfectly viable object to the console screen, but an `ng-bind` or `ng-show` directive fails to produce anything.

controllers.js

```
Controllers.controller("LocationController", ["$routeParams", "$scope", "$location", function($routeParams, $scope, $location) {

    if (!$routeParams.placeId) return $location.path("/");

    var PlaceService;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        PlaceService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(document.getElementById("locationContainer"));
    });

    PlaceService.getDetails({ placeId: $routeParams.placeId }, function(place, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            $scope.location = place;
            return console.log($scope.location);
        }
        return console.log("ERROR: " + status);
    });

}]);
```

location.html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <img ng-src="{{ location.icon }}">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-8">
                <p ng-bind="location.name"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="locationContainer"></div>
```

Console output:
 `Object { address_components=[9],  adr_address="<span class="street-addr...ountry-name">USA</span>",  formatted_address="935 W Wisconsin Ave, Milwaukee, WI 53233, USA",  more...}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your Async call.
replace

```
if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        $scope.location = place;
        return console.log($scope.location);
 }
```

with

```
$scope.$apply(function(){
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        $scope.location = place;
        return console.log($scope.location);
    }
}
```

Comment: Async calls are not happened in the angular $digest event.So we need to tell that angular bind this values. There is a official documentation for this. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/When-to-use-$scope.$apply()